# Convert tibble to long form when the variables consist of several parts

Tags: r, tidyr

I have such data

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tribble(
  ~id, ~a1, ~a2, ~a3, ~b1, ~b2, ~b3, ~c1, ~c2, ~c3,
    1,   1,   4,   7,  11,  14,  17,  21,  24,  27,
    2,   2,   5,   8,  12,  15,  18,  22,  25,  28,
    3,   3,   6,   8,  13,  16,  19,  23,  26,  29,
)
```

I would like to convert it to a long form, where the variable names contain two parts name (a, b, c) and number (1, 2, 3) which should become new variables in the long version of the table as below.

```
   id name nr data
1   1    a  1    1
2   2    a  1    2
3   3    a  1    3
4   1    a  2    4
5   2    a  2    5
6   3    a  2    6
7   1    a  3    7
8   2    a  3    8
9   3    a  3    8
10  1    b  1   11
11  2    b  1   12
12  3    b  1   13
13  1    b  2   14
14  2    b  2   15
15  3    b  2   16
16  1    b  3   17
17  2    b  3   18
18  3    b  3   19
19  1    C  1   21
20  2    C  1   22
21  3    C  1   23
22  1    C  2   24
23  2    C  2   25
24  3    C  2   26
25  1    C  3   27
26  2    C  3   28
27  3    C  3   29
```

Can it be done simply by using the functions in the `dplyr` package? I tried the `pivot_longer` effect was disappointing.

Any prompts are welcome.

Comment: What was disappointing? What did you try and what did you get exactly? It's helpful to be more specific. Also FYI `pivot_longer` is in tidyr, not dplyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do this in a couple of ways - i.e. first reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` excluding the 'id' column, then just `separate` the 'name' column into two by specifying the `sep` as a regex lookaround i.e. (as there is only a single lower case letter), split after the first occurrence of the letter (`(?<=[a-z])`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = 'name', values_to = 'data') %>%
   separate(name, into = c("name", 'nr'), sep = "(?<=[a-z])")
```

-output

```
 A tibble: 27 × 4
      id name  nr     data
   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1 a     1         1
 2     1 a     2         4
 3     1 a     3         7
 4     1 b     1        11
 5     1 b     2        14
 6     1 b     3        17
 7     1 c     1        21
 8     1 c     2        24
 9     1 c     3        27
10     2 a     1         2
# … with 17 more rows
```

---

Or another optioin is to append a suffix in the column names and then use `pivot_longer`

```
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   rename_with(~ str_c(., "_data"), -id) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = c("name", "nr", ".value"), 
       names_pattern = "^(.)(.)_(.*)")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. However, we have to wait a few more minutes to accept your solution :-)

Comment: However, I do not fully understand this notation "(? <= [A-z])". Could you just explain it to me?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has been asked before, but I can't find a good duplicate target. In the meantime, if you specify the regex to differentiate between the `name` portion and the `nr` portion of your column names, you can do it in one function call:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = c("name", "nr"), 
               values_to = "data", 
               names_pattern = "(^[a-z])(\\d$)")
#> # A tibble: 27 × 4
#>       id name  nr     data
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1     1 a     1         1
#>  2     1 a     2         4
#>  3     1 a     3         7
#>  4     1 b     1        11
#>  5     1 b     2        14
#>  6     1 b     3        17
#>  7     1 c     1        21
#>  8     1 c     2        24
#>  9     1 c     3        27
#> 10     2 a     1         2
#> # … with 17 more rows
```

Adapt the regex as needed if you have different column names in practice, but this separates them so that the first piece comes from a single lowercase letter at the beginning of the string, and the second piece comes from a single number at the end of the string.